# Finding items involving a particular category

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Item Service that is Called from an Asp.Net Core API Controller. The query gets all items in a particular category for display on an eCommerce web site (reactjs). The controller only returns json:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<EcommerceItemDto>> GetAllItemsAsync(string customerNumber, string category = "All", int page = 0, int pageSize = 9999)
    {
        IQueryable<Category> categories;

        if (category == "All")
        {
            categories = _context.Categories
                .Include(c => c.Children)
                .Include(p => p.Parent)
                .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution();
        }
        else
        {
            categories = _context.Categories
                .Where(n => n.Name == category)
                .Include(c => c.Children)
                .Include(p => p.Parent)
                .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution();
        }

        var items = await _context.EcommerceItems
            .FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM [cp].[GetEcommerceItemsView] WHERE [CustomerNumber] = {customerNumber}")
            .Include(x => x.Category)
            .Include(i => i.Images.OrderByDescending(d => d.Default))
            .OrderBy(i => i.ItemNumber)
            .Where(c => categories.Any(x => x.Children.Contains(c.Category)) || categories.Contains(c.Category))
            .Skip(page * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();

        var dto = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<EcommerceItemDto>>(items);

        return dto;
    }
```

I can show my Controller `Action`, `[cp].[GetEcommerceItemsView]` View, `EcommerceItem` Class, `EcommerceItemDto` Class, `Category` Class and `Images` Class if anyone thinks that will help. I have run `Tuning` on my Sql Database and applied the recommendations. I have bench-marked this using `_mapper.Map` as well as `.ProjectTo` and mapper.Map is faster by a hair. In my test Database, I only have about 65 Items with Images. But this request is taking about 1000 to 1500 ms.

**UPDATE**

As Per requested by @iSR5...

```
public class EcommerceItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Key]
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }

    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string ExtendedDesc { get; set; }
    
    public bool Featured { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric(19, 5)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric(19, 5)")]
    public decimal QtyOnHand { get; set; }

    public bool? Metadata1Active { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Metadata1Name { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Metadata1 { get; set; }
    
    ... // I have Twenty Matadata Groups

    public bool? Metadata20Active { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Metadata20Name { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Metadata20 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EcommerceItemImages> Images { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

My EcommerceItemDto:

```
public class EcommerceItemDto
{
    [Key]
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }

    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string ExtendedDesc { get; set; }

    public bool Featured { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric(19, 5)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric(19, 5)")]
    public decimal QtyOnHand { get; set; }

    public bool? Metadata1Active { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Metadata1Name { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Metadata1 { get; set; }

    ... // Same as EcommerceItem I have twenty Metadata groups
    
    public bool? Metadata20Active { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Metadata20Name { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Metadata20 { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<EcommerceItemImagesDto> Images { get; set; }
}
```

My Category Model:

```
[Table("bma_ec_categories")]
public class Category : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    [Column("category_id")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Column("parent_category_id")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("category_name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Category Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
    
    [Column("title")] 
    [StringLength(150)] 
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Column("description")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column("keywords")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }

    [Column("page_content", TypeName = "text")]
    public string PageContent { get; set; }

    [Column("banner_group_id")] 
    public int? BannerGroupId { get; set; }

    [Column("inactive")] 
    public byte? Inactive { get; set; }

    [Column("issitecategory")] 
    public byte Issitecategory { get; set; }

    [Column("metadata1_active")] 
    public byte Metadata1Active { get; set; }

    [Column("metadata1_name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Metadata1Name { get; set; }

    ...

    [Column("metadata20_active")] 
    public byte? Metadata20Active { get; set; }

    [Column("metadata20_name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Metadata20Name { get; set; }

    [Column("sort_order")] 
    public int? SortOrder { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EcommerceItem> Items { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Just to be complete, my `View`, it gets the calculated Price for the logged in user and flattens the category and item Metadata:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER VIEW [cp].[GetEcommerceItemsView]
AS
SELECT
    RTRIM(LTRIM(IV.ITEMNMBR)) AS ItemNumber
   ,RTRIM(LTRIM(IM.ITEMDESC)) AS ItemDescription
   ,ecItems.[extended_desc] AS ExtendedDesc
   ,CAST(ecItems.Featured AS BIT) AS Featured
   ,cat.category_name AS CategoryName
   ,CASE IM.PRICMTHD
        WHEN 1 THEN IV.UOMPRICE
        WHEN 2 THEN IV.UOMPRICE * IC.LISTPRCE / 100
        WHEN 3 THEN (IM.CURRCOST) * (1 + (IV.UOMPRICE / 100))
        WHEN 4 THEN (IM.STNDCOST) * (1 + (IV.UOMPRICE / 100))
        WHEN 5 THEN (IM.CURRCOST) / (1 - (IV.UOMPRICE / 100))
        WHEN 6 THEN (IM.STNDCOST) / (1 - (IV.UOMPRICE / 100))
        ELSE 0
    END AS Price
   ,IQ.QTYONHND AS QtyOnHand
   ,CAST(cat.[metadata1_active] AS BIT) AS [Metadata1Active]
   ,cat.[metadata1_name] AS [Metadata1Name]
   ,ecItems.[metadata1] AS [Metadata1]

   ...

   ,CAST(cat.[metadata20_active] AS BIT) AS [Metadata20Active]
   ,cat.[metadata20_name] AS [Metadata20Name]
   ,ecItems.[Metadata20] AS [Metadata20]
   ,C.CUSTNMBR AS CustomerNumber
FROM dbo.RM00101 AS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IV00108 AS IV
    ON C.PRCLEVEL = IV.PRCLEVEL
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IV00101 AS IM
    ON IM.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IV00102 AS IQ
    ON IQ.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
        AND IQ.RCRDTYPE = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IV00105 AS IC
    ON IC.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
        AND IV.CURNCYID = IC.CURNCYID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bma_ec_items AS ecItems
    ON ecItems.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bma_ec_item_category AS icat
    ON icat.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bma_ec_categories AS cat
    ON cat.category_id = icat.category_id
WHERE (IM.ITEMNMBR IN (SELECT
        ITEMNMBR
    FROM dbo.bma_ec_items
    WHERE (display_on_ecommerce = 1))
)
GO
```

*Special Note:* I am using Newtonsoft Json Serializer in my controller. I know There are faster Serializers out there.

**UPDATE 2**

As requested, Test Results follows:

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.0, OS=Windows 10.0.19043.1110 (21H1/May2021Update)
Intel Core i7-7700 CPU 3.60GHz (Kaby Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET SDK=5.0.302
[Host]     : .NET 5.0.8 (5.0.821.31504), X64 RyuJIT  [AttachedDebugger]
DefaultJob : .NET 5.0.8 (5.0.821.31504), X64 RyuJIT

| Method | IterationCount | Mean | Error | StdDev | Min | Max | Ratio | RatioSD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GetItems | 50 | 228.2 ms | 8.15 ms | 23.65 ms | 119.7 ms | 265.6 ms | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| GetItemsWithChanges | 50 | 231.0 ms | 4.60 ms | 10.66 ms | 211.3 ms | 253.1 ms | 1.04 | 0.22 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| GetItems | 100 | 455.8 ms | 9.04 ms | 24.29 ms | 414.9 ms | 522.0 ms | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| GetItemsWithChanges | 100 | 453.8 ms | 9.00 ms | 20.32 ms | 421.0 ms | 502.2 ms | 1.00 | 0.08 |

**UPDATE 3**

Test without categories:

| Method | IterationCount | Mean | Error | StdDev | Min | Max | Ratio | RatioSD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GetItems | 50 | 231.1 ms | 6.06 ms | 17.88 ms | 140.4 ms | 259.7 ms | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| GetItemsWithChangesWithoutCategories | 50 | 230.9 ms | 4.61 ms | 10.69 ms | 214.0 ms | 255.4 ms | 1.01 | 0.15 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| GetItems | 100 | 450.2 ms | 8.99 ms | 22.40 ms | 416.6 ms | 510.1 ms | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| GetItemsWithChangesWithoutCategories | 100 | 452.5 ms | 9.01 ms | 23.10 ms | 417.3 ms | 515.9 ms | 1.01 | 0.08 |

Comment: Please follow our title guidance: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please provide the `Category` and `EcommerceItem` models along with `EcommerceItemDto`. We need to know how the relationships works. Also, did you try to query the table and not the `View`  and see how it performs ?

Comment: @iSR5 Done+. My `View` get the custom Price for the logged-in user.

Comment: @Randy on `items`, comment out `.Include(x => x.Category)` and `.OrderBy(i => i.ItemNumber)` and in the raw sql add `TOP {pageSize} * FROM` and also `ORDER BY ItemNumber ASC;` test it, and let me know the performance difference.

Comment: @iSR5 Test results posted

Comment: @Randy thanks for the update, I need to confirm if the issue is from the DB side or the code part. Would you be kind and do another test excluding the `Category` part. So you only doing a direct query without a category. and check the SQL execution plan for it.

Comment: @iSR5 New test results posted

Comment: @Randy it seems that the bottleneck is the view itself.  You'll need to re-evaluate it and review its execution plan, do the proper indexes (also include full-text indexes if needed) to improve its performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed all the recommendations from RedGate's Sql Prompt (Modified my view to the one recommended change):

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER VIEW [cp].[GetEcommerceItemsView]
AS
SELECT
    RTRIM(LTRIM(IV.ITEMNMBR)) AS ItemNumber
   ,RTRIM(LTRIM(IM.ITEMDESC)) AS ItemDescription
   ,ecItems.[extended_desc] AS ExtendedDesc
   ,CAST(ecItems.Featured AS BIT) AS Featured
   ,cat.category_name AS CategoryName
   ,CASE IM.PRICMTHD
        WHEN 1 THEN IV.UOMPRICE
        WHEN 2 THEN IV.UOMPRICE * IC.LISTPRCE / 100
        WHEN 3 THEN (IM.CURRCOST) * (1 + (IV.UOMPRICE / 100))
        WHEN 4 THEN (IM.STNDCOST) * (1 + (IV.UOMPRICE / 100))
        WHEN 5 THEN (IM.CURRCOST) / (1 - (IV.UOMPRICE / 100))
        WHEN 6 THEN (IM.STNDCOST) / (1 - (IV.UOMPRICE / 100))
        ELSE 0
    END AS Price
   ,IQ.QTYONHND AS QtyOnHand
   ,CAST(cat.[metadata1_active] AS BIT) AS [Metadata1Active]
   ,cat.[metadata1_name] AS [Metadata1Name]
   ,ecItems.[metadata1] AS [Metadata1]

   ...   

   ,CAST(cat.[metadata20_active] AS BIT) AS [Metadata20Active]
   ,cat.[metadata20_name] AS [Metadata20Name]
   ,ecItems.[Metadata20] AS [Metadata20]
   ,C.CUSTNMBR AS CustomerNumber
FROM dbo.RM00101 AS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IV00108 AS IV
    ON C.PRCLEVEL = IV.PRCLEVEL
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IV00101 AS IM
    ON IM.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IV00102 AS IQ
    ON IQ.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
        AND IQ.RCRDTYPE = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IV00105 AS IC
    ON IC.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
        AND IV.CURNCYID = IC.CURNCYID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bma_ec_items AS ecItems
    ON ecItems.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR 
    AND ecItems.display_on_ecommerce = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bma_ec_item_category AS icat
    ON icat.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bma_ec_categories AS cat
    ON cat.category_id = icat.category_id
GO
```

Re-Ran the the tuning advisor and applied those Index creations. Then I switched to System.Text.Json from Newtonsoft.Json as my serializer in the Asp.net Core project. Re-Ran my Bench-Mark test:

| Method | IterationCount | Mean | Error | StdDev | Min | Max | Ratio | RatioSD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GetItems | 50 | 225.5 ms | 4.89 ms | 14.26 ms | 134.77 ms | 250.5 ms | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| GetItemsWithChangesWithoutCategories | 50 | 225.4 ms | 6.86 ms | 20.23 ms | 98.31 ms | 254.2 ms | 1.01 | 0.13 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| GetItems | 100 | 434.6 ms | 7.65 ms | 11.21 ms | 415.40 ms | 460.2 ms | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| GetItemsWithChangesWithoutCategories | 100 | 442.1 ms | 8.78 ms | 16.50 ms | 418.91 ms | 478.6 ms | 1.02 | 0.05 |

I guess this is optimized as it gets, unless I switch to Dapper.

**UPDATE**

To be fair to @iSR5, I discovered I had a typo in my username I was using to get the Authorization Token. I corrected it and re-ran the test:

| Method | IterationCount | Mean | Error | StdDev | Min | Max | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GetItems | 50 | 6.260 s | 0.1213 s | 0.1490 s | 6.012 s | 6.598 s | 1.00 |
| GetItemsWithChangesWithoutCategories | 50 | 2.036 s | 0.0407 s | 0.0543 s | 1.948 s | 2.162 s | 0.32 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| GetItems | 100 | 12.521 s | 0.2439 s | 0.2281 s | 12.048 s | 12.932 s | 1.00 |
| GetItemsWithChangesWithoutCategories | 100 | 4.135 s | 0.0790 s | 0.0739 s | 4.031 s | 4.242 s | 0.33 |

Comment: I don't think that dapper will solve the issue. You need to re-evaluate the view outside your code (using SSMS or any DBMS IDE), then apply the same query on it while `Execution Plan` is on. then review the execution plan, see what you can improve. And about the updated benchmark (with corrected username), it shows that it's even getting slower than before. (probably because of getting more data since you've corrected the username).

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea... I'd consider turning this query into a stored-procedure taking the `CustomerNumber` as a parameter and working directly with the data without the view. I'm pretty sure it's *slow* becuase it cannot take the advantage of `CustomerNumber` being probably indexed and it has to perform a full-scan of the view.

Comment: You could add indexes for that Stored Procedures.. and you get a +1 just to mention it (just because everybody is still so ORM it just hurts me)